# How to make a link this is connected to database in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, hyperlink

I am trying to make a php script which will get clients data from database in a table. the script works fine and is getting database fields correctly. Now i want to add a link beside every client info. The link should be like www.domain.com/check?clientid=$id&number=$phonenumber

How should i do this?
its a table and clients details are arranged in order. Please help me?

```
    // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, phonenumber, city, country, email FROM clients ORDER BY ID ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Country</th><th>Email</th><th>Send SMS</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "</td><td>" . $row["phonenumber"]. "</td><td>" . $row["city"]. " " 

. $row["country"]. "</td><td>" . $row["email"]. "</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: can't you just do something like echo "www.domain.com/check?clientid=".$row["id"]."&number=".$row['phonenumber']

Comment: ```$link = 'http://yourdomain.com/check?cientid=%d&number=%s';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo sprintf($link, $rw['id'], $row['phonenumber']);
    }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Marcosh (in the comments), so that would give you this code (between the if(...) { and } else):

```
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Country</th><th>Email</th><th>Send SMS</th><th>Link to page</th></tr>";
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]."</td><td>" . $row["phonenumber"]. "</td><td>" . $row["city"]. " ". $row["country"]. "</td><td>" . $row["email"]. "</td><td><a href='www.domain.com/check?clientid=" . $row["id"] . "&number=" . $row['phonenumber'] . ">Click me!</a></td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

Note 1: This will add a link with the text "Click me!". I think you may want to change that. You may also want to change the header (currently "Link to page")
Note 2: If you use php 5.5 or later, you can also use

```
echo "blablabla<td>{$row['id']}</td>etc..."
```

instead of

```
echo "blablabla<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>etc..."
```

Comment: thanks! it worked! now can you help me with this? i want a text field in the table and what ever entered in the text field, when i click"Click Me" the url should be like http://www.domain.com/check?id=xxm&message=(what ever entered in field) ????

Comment: @Sohail Just add `<td><form action='http://domain.com/check?id=" . $row['id'] . "' method='GET'><textarea name='message' rows='10' cols='50'>Leave a message</textarea><input type='submit' value='Click me!'></form></td>` after the </a> in the while-loop, and `<th>Message</th>` after <th>Link to page</th>. Note 1: this uses an absolute URL with http://, you may want to change that to https or add www. Note 2: 'Click me!' might confuse some users, I suggest you use 'Submit' or 'Post'. Note 3: I used the ID from the query, you can change it to xxm if you meant that as literal text.

Comment: its not wokring.. when i click click me it.. the form actions is not getting id in url... only message is coming.. here is my code: <td><form action='https://control.domain.com/api/sendhttp.php?authkey=74685AiSz3dkBxxxxx&mobiles=" . $row['phonenumber'] . "&sender=xxx&route=4&message=' method='GET'><textarea name='message' 

rows='10' cols='50'>Leave a message</textarea><input type='submit' value='Click me!'></form></td>

Comment: @Sohail Well, your comment got a bit shortened (the action was interpreted as an actual URL instead of code), I don't know exactly what you mean, and the comments are a bad place to figure this out, so I suggest you post this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help @ivo and i have learned how to get this thing done:

```
<td><form action='https://control.domain.com/api/sendhttp.php' method='GET'><input type='hidden' name='authkey' value='74685AiSz3dkBX5467773f'><input type='hidden' name='mobiles' value='" . $row['phonenumber'] . "'><input type='hidden' name='sender' value='hostbi'><input type='hidden' name='route' value='4'><textarea name='message' cols='55'>Leave a message</textarea><input type='submit' value='Click me!'></form></td>
```